# Bond Index Return from Yield Curve Data

Tags: bond, yield-curve, index, return

I am trying to compare fund returns with benchmark returns. I have some yield curve data (some of them calculated by Bloomberg) but not bond price or return data. Is there any way to get bond returns from yield curve data? Let's say you have Hungarian corporate bond yield curve.

I kind of guess it is hard because we need to take duration, convexity into account but would appreciate if there is any rule of thumb etc.

Second question: for a specific bond, instead of getting price from YTM then calculate return based on price, may i just do it by using YTM directly?

Best,